# concat age column of multiple dataframes into one and plot histogram

Tags: python, pandas, plot

i am trying to plot histogram distribution of age column from multiple dataframes. 
Following is piece of code i am trying but it gives be blank plots.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

filelist = glob.glob('/Users/kadb/Desktop/participants_tsv_files/*.tsv')
# fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# ax.xaxis.set_ticks(df.index)
# ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(df['g'])
plt.figure()
for file in filelist:
    df = pd.read_table(file)
    if 'age' in df.columns:
        df = df[~df["age"].isin(["n/a"])] # remove n/a values 
        result = result.append(df,ignore_index=True)
        result = pd.concat([df,result], axis=1)
        plt.hist(result, normed=1, facecolor='green')
```

example tsv file:

```
participant_id  gender  age physioSampling  restAcquisiotion
sub-01  M   26  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-02  M   21  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-03  M   22  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-04  M   23  N/A after_cuedSGT
sub-05  M   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-06  M   19  n/a before_cuedSGT
sub-07  F   18  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-08  F   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-09  M   20  40-60   before_cuedSGT
sub-10  F   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-11  F   20  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-12  M   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-13  F   31  50-60   before_cuedSGT
```

Comment: I think you want `axis=0` in your `pd.concat` statement, because you're trying to add more rows to a single 'age' column, not create multiple `age` columns. also, I'd guess you just want to plot once at the end right? if so, `plt.hist` shouldn't be indented inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Do you want to plot multiple histograms or only 1 (for all ages in all tables)?

Comment: Try initializing the result list before the loop (i.e. `results = []`). Then only do the `pandas.concat` after all `df` is appended to the results list but pulling it out of the loop.

Comment: @DenisKuzin i want to plot only one histogram

Comment: @CiaranWelsh I tried your suggestion but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea: 1) collect `ages` from all dataframes; 2) plot histogram

intro

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
filelist = glob.glob('/Users/kadb/Desktop/participants_tsv_files/*.tsv')
```

collect ages for hist

```
ages = []
for file in filelist:
    df = pd.read_table(file)
    if 'age' in df.columns:
        df = df[~df["age"].isin(["n/a"])] # remove n/a values 
        ages.extend(df.age.values)
```

plot hist

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7,7))
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("age")
plt.xlabel("density")
plt.hist(ages, normed=1, facecolor='green')
plt.show()
```